# inconsistent 404 error on API function

Tags: c#, azure, debugging

I promise I searched for the answer...

My application consist of both a Mobile backend in azure and a Web-client application that makes calls upon this back-end.

I have run across a bizarre bug that creates 404 not found errors when calling a Http Get function on my backend.

The bizarre part of this issue is that the error is random. It is probably a %50 chance that I might get a 404 or a 200 ok response from the server. This only happens on one specific method that was recently added.

I am wondering if breaking the back-end into instances might have created a non-identical copy of my app.

I removed the instance, and the specific api I have been calling is not longer available on the published version it is visible while running on debug.. I get 100% error on the published version now.

What is wrong with azure? cleaning and rebuilding the back-end does nothing.

---

```
 [Route("api/UserProject/{projectId}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetUserProjectByProjectId(int projectId)
    {
        //Get all UserProject 
        List<DTO.User> userList = new List<DTO.User>();

        DataTable UserdataTable = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset("dbo.UserGetByProjectId", projectId).Tables[0];

        if (UserdataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dataRow in UserdataTable.Rows)
            {
                DTO.User u = new DTO.User();

                Map.DataToObject(dataRow, u);

                userList.Add(u);
            }
        }

        return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, userList);
```

### }

going to the api/help page on Debug the UserProject route works and is shown in DEBUG mode, but as soon as I publish the app the UserProject function is not longer anywhere to be found.

Comment: Does every endpoint return 404? Would be easier if you provide more specific info.

Comment: I am having difficulty trying to find out what info would help. It is only one specific api function that is returning 404 it is not visible when I publish, but I can see it just fine on debug.

Comment: Can you show us this function?

Comment: function has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow I finally fixed it. I did the one thing I though would be useless and it worked.

I restarted the service from the azure portal....

My opinion: I guess the created intances where the ones working of the latest version while the original was unable to be updated and the only way to make the original update was to restart the whole thing.

I really don't know why this happened, if you guys want to comment on this please do so.

Comment: It would not be Microsoft if you did not have to restart something .
I also get random 404 errors on my `ApiController`. They occur very little but still occur. I will try your solution.